# React run build error

Tags: reactjs

I have a running Reactjs app without errors but when I try to run `npm run build` I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! react-registration@0.1.0 lint: `esw webpack.config.* src tools --color`
npm ERR! Failed at the react-registration@0.1.0 lint script.
npm ERR! react-registration@0.1.0 prebuild: `npm run clean-dist && npm run lint && npm run test`
npm ERR! Failed at the react-registration@0.1.0 prebuild script.
```

This is the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/serj/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/serj/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'lint' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.9.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prelint', 'lint', 'postlint' ]
5 info lifecycle react-registration@0.1.0~prelint: react-registration@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle react-registration@0.1.0~lint: react-registration@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle react-registration@0.1.0~lint: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle react-registration@0.1.0~lint: PATH: /home/serj/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/
node-gyp-bin:/home/serj/Desktop/Symfony/DEPLOY/react/node_modules/.bin:/home/serj/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/
npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/serj/Desktop/Symfony/DEPLOY/react/node_modules/.bin:/home/serj/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin:/home/serj/bin:/
home/serj/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/serj/.composer/vendor/bin
9 verbose lifecycle react-registration@0.1.0~lint: CWD: /home/serj/Desktop/Symfony/DEPLOY/react
10 silly lifecycle react-registration@0.1.0~lint: Args: [ '-c', 'esw webpack.config.* src tools --color' ]
11 silly lifecycle react-registration@0.1.0~lint: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle react-registration@0.1.0~lint: Failed to exec lint script
13 verbose stack Error: react-registration@0.1.0 lint: `esw webpack.config.* src tools --color`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/serj/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.j
s:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/serj/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spa
wn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid react-registration@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /home/serj/Desktop/Symfony/DEPLOY/react
16 verbose Linux 4.10.0-38-generic
17 verbose argv "/home/serj/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node" "/home/serj/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/npm" "run" "lint"
18 verbose node v8.9.4
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error react-registration@0.1.0 lint: `esw webpack.config.* src tools --color`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the react-registration@0.1.0 lint script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Not sure where to search with such a type of error. If somebody has any suggestions I would be very thankful.

Comment: Could you link to a repo of the project? Or the package.json and webpack config at least. A log isn't really much to go on if we don't know what's going on in your build system

Comment: this is my git: https://github.com/scaniusin/reacwithapi

Comment: It looks like it's failing on the "lint" script, meaning there might be a linter error in your code somewhere. Strange (and bothersome) that it doesn't outright say where the linter error is, though. Try running the lint script manually through `npm run lint` and see if that shows anything useful.